# How can Pact of the Chain warlocks' familiars heal?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars, healing

I've been looking around everywhere, but I cannot seem to find out how a [Pact of the Chain warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#PactBoon)'s familiar might recover hitpoints. Regular [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) familiars only have 1 hp, so it's entirely moot for them, but Chain familiars have enough HP that they can potentially take damage and survive.

I don't see any indication that they can benefit from long rests, as they are not characters, but this does seem like the logical conclusion. They certainly don't appear to have hit dice with which to heal.

Comment: Some of the regular familiars have 2 or even (gasp!) 3 hit points, so this question does actually apply to them too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## They can use hit dice, or you can heal them

Any creature that has HP has hit dice. For example, a Sprite has an averaged HP of 2, but that's because it has a 1d4 hitdice. So if that Sprite takes 1 damage, it can use a 1d4 hit dice during a short rest to recover.

A Pseudodragon has a whopping 2d4+2 HP, meaning it has 2 d4 hitdice to use during its short rest.

Comment: So they do, in essence, function like PCs with respect to healing? Would this imply that they also heal during long rests?

Comment: @Neil yes, they can heal during long rests - any creature can, unless specifically specified differently. See this related question: [How can I heal undead creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53556/how-can-i-heal-undead-creatures)

Answer (score 8):

## Familiars do have hit dice

Taking a look at the stats for, say, an [imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp), you can see that the health is listed as:

> **Hit Points:** 10 (3d4 + 3)

So they have 3 hit die, which are d4. These can be spend during a short rest to recover hit points.