# How can familiars benefit from the Aid spell's temporary Hit Points?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, hit-points

I am about to propose an idea to a friend of mine who plays a Wizard, and whom we have finally convinced should get his *familiar* up and running.  (I play a Cleric in this party).  He is concerned that his owl with only 1 HP will too easily die.  This is a valid concern based on the experiences we had in our first D&D 5e campaign; my brother's wizard's owl familiar died with some frequency.  (This question was inspired by [a previous question about familiars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132809/22566).)

I am about to propose that he not worry, since when I cast [*aid*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aid) on the party, I can include his familiar.  What I am not sure of is whether the familiar (who I think qualifies) to receive the temporary hit points for *aid*, can be healed if it takes damage less than lethal.

The *aid* spell says:

> Your spell bolsters your allies with toughness and resolve. Choose up to three creatures within range. Each target’s hit point maximum and current hit points increase by 5 for the duration.  (Basic Rules, p. 83)

**When my cleric casts *aid*, can my wizard ally's owl familiar get 5 temporary hit points and be healed if it takes damage?**

This would improve its chances of survival considerably.

Illustration: I cast *aid*, owl has 6 HP (1+ 5 Temp).  Owl takes 4 HP damage. Can I heal it back up to 6 HP after or during the battle?  I am not sure if these bonus HP are like temporary HP, or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *Aid* increases maximum hit points not temporary hit points

Temporary hit points are different as they disappear when they are lost. The *aid* spell actually changes a creature's hit point maximum. Because of this they are treated as the creature's own hit points and can heal like normal.

### Yes it can affect the familiar

*Aid* affects any creature and familiars are creatures:

> the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form

All forms to choose from are creatures.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to accept this.  Oops!