# Does casting Beacon of Hope followed by Cure Wounds deal max damage against undead in the area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, undead, healing

If you cast *beacon of hope* and there are undead within the 30ft range, can you affect them and then cast *cure wounds* on them to deal a full 30 damage (3d10) to them?

Answer (score 32):

[*Cure wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) has **no effect on undead**, as stated in its description.

> This spell has no effect on undead or constructs.

You might be confused with the previous edition positive-negative energy system, where you can deals damage with healing (positive energy) to undead. [5e does not use this system anymore.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53556/how-can-i-heal-undead-creatures)

You can target an undead with [*beacon of hope*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope), but it will have no interaction with *cure wounds*, as the description of *cure wounds* says. Even if your DM misses/ignores this part, it will only maximize the healing rolls it receives.