# Can undead characters use healing spells as normal to heal other characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, undead, healing

I've been trying to create a character (a Skeleton Bard using [this homebrew race option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9MDh.jpg)) and I know that there are some spells that cannot heal the undead. But what about the other way around?

As a skeleton, would I be able to use *Cure Wounds* or *Healing Word* on my other (living) teammates?

I like the idea of not being able to be healed by certain spells because it would be interesting to play around with. But I feel like it would be rather difficult as a healer if I can't use one of the more vital spells in my kit.

Comment: Have you asked your GM for their thoughts on undead casting healing spells and any limitations therein?

Comment: "Dead Immortality. You do not age. Given time, the necromantic energies that sustain you will heal most wounds you take at approximately the same rate as a mortal, and your hit dice function as normal."

Comment: @Medix2 No, not yet actually. I guess that's what it should come down to in the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## *Cure Wounds*/*Healing Word* heal the living and do not affect the undead

[*Cure Wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) states:

> A creature you touch regains a number of hit points equal to 1d8 +
> your spellcasting ability modifier. **This spell has no effect on undead**
> or constructs.

[*Healing Word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word) states:

> A creature of your choice that you can see within range regains hit
> points equal to 1d4 + your spellcasting ability modifier. **This spell
> has no effect on undead** or constructs.

**Unless I missed something** from the homebrew race you shared, you are indeed undead and can cast your bard spells normally.

Being undead does not change how the spells work, but it changes its effect on you, of course, since you are undead.

I was surprised to see that ***Inflict Wounds* does not heal the undead in 5e**. (Necrotic damage does not heal them, some are immune or resistant to it so... it hurts them)

On how to heal yourself as an undead creature, the question [How can I heal undead creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53556/51979) can help you.

### In Short:

Yes, your bard spells will heal your living comrades, but you will have to find other ways to heal yourself since they don't heal you.

Comment: Thanks for the info! As for finding other ways to heal myself, I've been referring to this [this tweet by Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/19/healing-options-for-undead/) as well.